# Android device connection with classic bluetooth and BLE at the same time

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am new to android bluetooth programming, wanted to know about bluetooth connections. I have connected  a tab to another android phone using ble,  at the same can I connect the tab to classic bluetooths as well? Is this possible to connect tab to a ble device and another android phone at the same time?

Answer (score 3):

Yes this should be possible and Android doesn't impose any restrictions on this. Have a look at the links below for more information:-

- [Simultaneous Bluetooth and BLE connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19356144/simultaneous-bluetooth-and-bluetooth-le-connections-is-it-possible)
- [Bluetooth SPP and BLE connection at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65578011/is-it-possible-to-have-an-bluetooth-spp-connection-and-ble-gatt-connection-in-an)
- [Bluetooth classic vs BLE on Android](https://www.thedroidsonroids.com/blog/bluetooth-classic-vs-bluetooth-low-energy-ble)
- [The ultime guide to Android BLE development](https://punchthrough.com/android-ble-guide/?utm_source=BlogEmail&utm_medium=Email&utm_campaign=BlogRoundUp&mc_cid=9113555d36&mc_eid=767bbcdc1b)